# Grails 3.2 - how to get java.sql.Connection in plugin

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-plugin

I have a plugin that needs a java.sql.Connection object obtained from the main application database connection.  I have code like this:

```
def dataSource

def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
def conn = sql.getConnection()
```

and the connection is always null.  What is the correct means of getting a connection object?  Using an Oracle database:

```
type: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
factory: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory
driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Grails 3.2.5

Comment: The class in your plugin, is it a class that can get beans injected (ie. a Service class)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is to get Sql out of the mix.  It was a holdover from some previous version of something.  So,

```
def dataSource

def conn = dataSource.connection
```